Best way of showing filter options in list/reports mobile app
I need to display reports (long list of items) in my mobile app (in Flutter), along with search and filter options. Currently, I'm presenting filters in a pop-up, but I'm looking to improve this. I have planned to showcase the filters in a bottom sheet.
What other methods would be best for enhancing the user experience to show filters with multiple options in a mobile app?
My current screen looks like this :


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Bottom sheet sound pretty good! For filter options under each section, are them individual to each other? Otherwise you can use chips rather than drop-downs.
